# How to find and click on an excel file, given that the file name changes?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
<a id="hlExcel" href="Reports\DC_REG_638123088090882623.xls" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Excel.gif" alt="Click to view a Excel version"></a>
```

How do I find and click on this excel file that I have to download everyday, given that the file name changes every day. I have tried this:-

> link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('["href="Reports"]')
>
> link.click()

I am using python Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```
<a id="hlExcel" href="Reports\DC_REG_638123088090882623.xls" target="_blank">
    <img src="Images/Excel.gif" alt="Click to view a Excel version">
</a>
```

To click on the ***clickable*** element even though the file name changes every day ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#hlExcel > img[alt='Click to view a Excel version']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='hlExcel']/img[@alt='Click to view a Excel version']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a partial match maybe. Is the DC_REG common in all file names ? If you know a pattern which will be part of the name irrespective of how many times the name changes, you could look for that pattern. Something like

```
link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="REG"][href$=".xls"]')

link.click()
```

Comment: Ho would I change this to take into account that the DC part is common.

Comment: Try replacing REG with DC in my code besides the href

Comment: I am able to find the link with this code:-                                                                 link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[href$=".xls"]') but now I receive this error "ElementNotInteractableException: Message:" but when I click on the file on  the actual website it downloads

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).